# Strict standards issue with Drupal 7 custom module

Tags: drupal-7

The following error message is displayed when I visit the homepage:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\vb-15-05-2018-2\sites\all\modules\vb_ymlp\vb_ymlp.module on line 40
```

This is coming from a custom module and the line within the `if` statement is the issue.  Does this point to a bigger issue or is there a simple solution?

```
function vb_ymlp_block_view($delta = ""){
  module_load_include('inc', 'vb_ymlp', 'vb_ymlp.form');
  $block = array();

  if($delta == 'vb_ymlp_block'){
    // the line below is causing this error
    $block['content'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('vb_ymlp_form'));
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to set value as function as you set drupal_render()

You have to get it first and then set it to the content variable

Like you have to do

```
function vb_ymlp_block_view($delta = ""){
  module_load_include('inc', 'vb_ymlp', 'vb_ymlp.form');
  $block = array();

  if($delta == 'vb_ymlp_block'){
    // the line below is causing this error
    $content = drupal_get_form('vb_ymlp_form');
    $content = drupal_render($content);
    $block['content'] = $content;
  }
  return $block; 
}
```

HOPE THIS SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM

THANKS